# bootstrap data toggle tab is working only one tab but the other tab is not working

Tags: bootstrap-modal

```
<div class="widget-header" style="margin-top: 5%;"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="<c:if test="${tab != 'LETTERS'}">selected active </c:if>inline headerDivider">
            <a class="<c:if test="${tab != 'LETTERS'}">active </c:if>header" href="action" data-toggle="tab"><Regulations</a>
        </li>

        <li class="<c:if test="${tab == 'LETTERS'}">selected active </c:if>inline headerDivider">
           <a class="<c:if test="${tab == 'LETTERS'}">>selected active </c:if>header" href="action" data-toggle="tab">Letters</a>
        </li>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${tab != 'LETTERS'}">
                <a data-href="action" class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-reload="regulationDiv">Manage Regulations</a>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <a data-href="action" class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-reload="letterDiv">Add Letter</a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="overflow: auto; max-height:60vh;" class="tab-content">
    <c:if test="${tab != 'LETTERS'}">
        <div id="regulationDiv" data-url='action'>
            <jsp:include page="regulations.jsp"/>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${tab == 'LETTERS'}">
       <div id="letterDiv" data-url='action'>
            <jsp:include page="letters.jsp"/>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

First tab by default its working second tab there is no event or click, looks like disabled tab.Am I missing something to include in div elements, I tried many ways seems no solution yet to me.